# Looping thought multilevel array php

Tags: php

I have an array in php that looks like this:

```
print_r($myArray);  

Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [age] => 1
        [time] => 2
        [name] => james
        [size] => 12
        [hieght] => 13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [age] => 3
        [time] => 1
        [name] => tim
        [size] => 12
        [hieght] => 13
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [age] => 1
        [time] => 2
        [name] => john
        [size] => 132
        [hieght] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [age] => 1
        [time] => 2
        [name] => logan
        [size] => 12
        [hieght] => 11
    ) 
)
```

Im trying to loop though every item and save each "size" in a new array. I have looked into solutions for pulling out the "size" from each inner array but cant seem to get it right:

```
$all_sizes = array();
foreach($myArray as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        if($key == "size") {

        } 
    }
}
```

I am new to PHP so im struggling on the proper syntax for this situation.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 

<br />

Comment: The error you point it's not in that code fragment. But the answer from @aldrin27 it's more effecient than you original code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the next foreach()

```
$all_sizes = array();
  foreach($myArray as $value => $getSize) {
    $all_sizes[] = $getSize['size'];
  }
print_r($all_sizes);
```

Comment: ... Remove the next foreach() `$all_sizes = array_column($myArray, "size");`

Comment: wait Im confused with your second comment, what should it look like all together?